# jQuery 2 dropdowns equal values different outcome

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I am stuck in my conditional jQuery, as I am not sure how to apply the || and && in this situation or maybe something else need to be added.

**Scenario:**
2 dropdowns with both same options, by selecting the 1st (source) and selecting the 2nd (target) certain div element will be shown.
Dropdown 1: apple, orange, banana
Dropdown 2: apple, orange, banana

When you select dropdown 1 apple and dropdown 2 banana, should show a different element than dropdown 1 banana and dropdown 2 apple. This is a simplified scenario, my real scenario has on both sides 40 dropdown options.

**What I started:**

```
    $("#div-1, #div-2").hide();
    $("select[name=fruit-1],select[name=fruit-2]").change(function () {
        if ($("select[name=fruit-1]").val() == "Apple"||$("select[name=fruit-2]").val() == "Banana"||$("select[name=fruit-2]").val() == "Orange") {
                $("#div-1").show();
        }
    });
    $("select[name=fruit-1],select[name=fruit-2]").change(function () {
        if ($("select[name=fruit-2]").val() == "Apple"||$("select[name=fruit-1]").val() == "Banana"||$("select[name=fruit-1]").val() == "Orange") {
                $("#div-2").show();
        }
    });
```

Because of the above OR-operator it makes now combinations with all options. Of course I could fix this individually with an AND-operator, but I have 40x40 options, so I need to have groups.

How do I keep these separated so they don't combine?

Comment: Use a single `change` event, after your first `if` and `else if` and the 2nd clause.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for the suggestion, could you make an example of this, how I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a logic array here, simply as the elements you're wanting to show could be anything, along with the logic combinations could be anything, like this:

```
// find elements
var logic = [
   { fruit1: 'apple', fruit2: 'banana', element: '#div-1' },
   { fruit1: 'banana', fruit2: 'apple', element: '#div-2' }
];

$('.showableDiv').hide();

// Add class of fruit-dropdown to selects, just to make this a little easier to read.
$(".fruit-dropdown").on("change", function () {
    // Hide all other divs? Best to add a class on them, i.e. the div-1 and div-2 classes.
    $('.showableDiv').hide();

    var logicResult = logic.filter(a => a.fruit1 == $("select[name=fruit-1]").val() && a.fruit2 == $("select[name=fruit-2]").val());

    if(logicResult.length) $(logicResult[0].element).show();
});
```

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/650234/

orrr...

```
// find elements
var logic = [
    { fruit1: 'apple', fruit2: 'banana', element: '#div-1', reverseElement: '#div-2' }
];

$('.showableDiv').hide();

// Add class of fruit-dropdown to selects, just to make this a little easier to read.
$(".fruit-dropdown").on("change", function () {
    // Hide all other divs? Best to add a class on them, i.e. the div-1 and div-2 classes.
    $('.showableDiv').hide();

    var logicResult = logic.filter(a => a.fruit1 == $("select[name=fruit-1]").val() && a.fruit2 == $("select[name=fruit-2]").val());

    if(logicResult.length) { 
      $(logicResult[0].element).show();
    } else {
        logicResult = logic.filter(a => a.fruit1 == $("select[name=fruit-2]").val() && a.fruit2 == $("select[name=fruit-1]").val());
       if(logicResult.length) $(logicResult[0].reverseElement).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like a great answer, and it makes sense. However, the code is not working in your jsFiddle. Can you please check?